# Force FindFormula to avoid Piecewise in the result?

Tags: functions, fitting

Is it possible to provide any arguments to [`FindFormula`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindFormula.html) to force it to avoid using [`Piecewise`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html) in the result, but instead try to find the best fit using expressions constructed only from functions specified in [`TargetFunctions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TargetFunctions.html) option?

---

To give a concrete example, consider e.g. the data [in this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/256747/12). `FindFormula` will always return a `Piecewise` expression with many pieces:

[image]

In many (most?) applications, it is reasonable to assume that the function is smooth, and a piecewise result is simply not useful.

Comment: Does adding `SpecificityGoal-> "Low"` help?  The documentation states that this results in simpler fits.  My unsolicited advice is to avoid `FindFormula` completely or accept the fits that it provides.  Any calculations with a piecewise fit will still be performed by a computer and not by hand so what exactly is the downside to having a piecewise result?

Comment: @JimB I need a smooth (infinitely differentiable) function. `Piecewise` results often are not even continuous.

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov  This problem has no unique solution and also depends on version. For instance in v. 12.2 code `fit = FindFormula[table1, x, Method -> "NonLinearRegression",  SpecificityGoal -> "High",  TargetFunctions -> {Plus, Times, Power, Sin, Cos, Tan, Cot, Log, Sqrt, Csc, Abs, Exp}]`  has outcome  `0.317828 - 2. E^(-.901747 x)  + 0.511021 x` while in v.12.3 it gives `0.317828 - 2.2358 E^(-1. x) Sqrt[x] + 0.511021 x`. How it can solve your problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`FindFormula` has an undocumented option `Method`, its possible values can be printed by the following code:

```
sym = First@Names@"*`iFindFormula"
Begin[Context@#&@sym];
Keys[#][[1,2]] & /@ Rest@DownValues@#&@Symbol@sym
End[];
```

With my Mathematica 12.2.0.0, it gives:

```
{
  Automatic,
  "NonLinearRegression",
  {"SimulatedAnnealing", "WalksNumber" -> m_},
  "SimulatedAnnealing",
  {"SimulatedAnnealing", initial_},
  {"ParallelTempering", "WalksNumber" -> m_},
  "ParallelTempering",
  {"ParallelTempering", initial_},
  "Piecewise"
}
```

Do not use `Automatic` and `"Piecewise"` (although this one won't pass the argument check of FindFormula), then you can get rid of the `Piesewise` results.

With proper option values of `SpecificityGoal` and `TargetFunctions`, better results can be obtained:

```
fit = FindFormula[
  table1,
  x
, Method -> "NonLinearRegression"
, SpecificityGoal -> "High"
, TargetFunctions -> {Plus, Times, Power, Sin, Cos, Tan, Cot, Log, Sqrt, Csc, Sec, Abs, Exp}]
Show[
  Plot[fit, {x, 0, 1+Length@table1}],
  ListPlot@table1
]
```

[image: output]

Comment: It is nice code (+1), but with version 12.3 it gives `0.317828 + 0.511021 x - 2.2358 E^(-0.866132 (0.107106 + x)) Sec[19. x]`, and it looks not so good as in your plot.

Comment: @AlexTrounev `FindFormula` acts randomly, and may change by version. It may be helpful to adjust some options and keep trying.

Comment: If we remove `Sec` from options, then we have in v.12.3 `0.317828 - 2.2358 E^(-1. x) Sqrt[x] + 0.511021 x`. It is differ from above as well.  Also I don't understand how it could solve problem of differentiation.

Comment: @AlexTrounev The algorithm uses ramdom numbers. `BlockRandom` may help.

Comment: How `BlockRandom` may help if we have different formulas in different versions?

Comment: @AlexTrounev I'm not sure.