# Finding recurrence relation from an inexact numerical sequence

Tags: data, filtering, recursion, signal-processing, sequence

Consider the recurrence relationship

```
d[0] = 0;
d[i_] := (1 + Sqrt[1 + 4 d[i - 1]^2])/2 /; i >= 1
```

which generates the following sequence (generated by using `Table[d[i], {i, 0, 50}] // N`):

```
Table1 = {0., 1., 1.61803, 2.19353, 2.74979, 3.29488, 3.8326, 4.36508, 
4.89362, 5.4191, 5.94212, 6.46312, 6.98243, 7.50031, 8.01695, 
8.53253, 9.04717, 9.56097, 10.074, 10.5864, 11.0982, 11.6095, 
12.1203, 12.6306, 13.1405, 13.65, 14.1591, 14.668, 15.1765, 15.6847, 
16.1927, 16.7004, 17.2079, 17.7151, 18.2222, 18.729, 19.2357, 
19.7422, 20.2485, 20.7547, 21.2607, 21.7666, 22.2724, 22.778, 
23.2835, 23.7888, 24.2941, 24.7992, 25.3043, 25.8092, 26.3141}
```

Can we go in the opposite direction? In other words, is there a way one could find out this underlying recurrence relation (or a good enough approximate recurrence relation by data fitting, etc) in `Mathematica` given `Table1`? One could try `FindSequenceFunction`, but it did not work even after removing the `// N` as pointed out by `@MarcoB` in the comment. Any tips/suggestions regarding this will be much appreciated!

Comment: A small clarification: `FindSequenceFunction` works for exact numerical or symbolic values, and not just integer values. Nevertheless, even after removing the `// N` from your code, unfortunately `FindSequenceFunction` can't find a closed-form expression for your sequence.

Comment: "or a good enough approximate recurrence relation by data fitting" <- You could use `FindFormula`, e.g. `FindFormula@Partition[Table1, 2, 1]`. This produces a linear fit for the recurrence part, which is pretty close to be fair, but I'm not sure if it's useful for you in the context of recursion. It would be interesting to think about implementing a recursion-appropriate cost function for such fitting.

Comment: This is a good idea, @Szabolcs , thanks! I will try your suggestion and report the findings in the comment. While in this case I already know the data generating recurrence relation exactly, for the other cases `FindFormula`-based methods may be a good enough alternative.

Comment: @Szabolcs , the fit provided by `FindFormula` is good enough for my purpose (for the cases where I do not know the recursion in advance). Thanks again!

Comment: The problem with fitting only the recursion relation is that the error may become larger and larger as the recursion is applied more and more times.  It would make sense to find a formula which minimizes the total error for `k` recursion steps, instead of just for one recursion step. But I don't think this is possible with `FindFormula`.  If you already have a formula, and just want the parameters, it would be possible with a direct use of `NMinimize` / `FindMinimum`.

Comment: Yes, I see your point. Sounds good, I will try the suggestion for a candidate recursion function (parametrized) and see how well `FindMinimum`/`NMinimize` type functions do in finding the parameters.